# Adding custom javascript to nested_form (Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, nested-forms

I using Ryan Bates' [nested form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) in my rails app, but I want to add some custom javascript to it as well.

My view (.slim):

```
= f.fields_for :student do |builder|
    = builder.input :uni
    = builder.input :grad
    = builder.input :degree_type
    = builder.input :degree_abbr

    = builder.fields_for :majors do |maj|
        = maj.input :name, label: "Name of major"
        = maj.input :foo1_id, collection: Foo.all, input_html: {id: 'foo_1'}
        = maj.input :foo2_id, collection: [], input_html: {id: 'foo_2'}
        = maj.input :foo3_id, collection: [], input_html: {id: 'foo_3'}
        = maj.link_to_remove "Remove this major ▲"
    = builder.link_to_add "Add another major", :majors
```

My javascript:

```
$("#foo_1").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/welcome/update_foo',
        type: 'GET',
        format: 'js',
        dataType: 'script',
        data: {
            foo_1_id: $('#foo_1 option:selected').val()
        }
    });
});
$("#foo_2").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/welcome/update_foo',
        type: 'GET',
        format: 'js',
        dataType: 'script',
        data: {
            foo_2_id: $('#foo_2 option:selected').val()
        }
    });
});
```

This all works nice and dandy. I'm using the ajax request to dynamically update the dropdowns (When I select an option from `#foo_1`, `#foo_2` populates with the correct information). Here's my problem though: when I click on `Add another major`, I don't know how to assign and retrieve these new inputs' ids. The dropdowns under this second major do not populate correctly.

Are they given `#foo_1`, `#foo_2`, and `#foo_3` as well? If so, how do I differentiate between them in my javascript `.change()` method?

His [README](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form#jquery) shows you can capture `nested:fieldAdded`, but I'm unsure what steps to take from here.

Rails 4.1.5
ruby 2.1.2p95

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the javascript located? You could use a mixture between `find` and `closest` in jQuery.

Comment: @kobaltz It's currently just embedded at the bottom of the page, but I'm planning on moving out into it's own file in the future

Answer (score 0):

With the `nested_form` the ids are used to identify uniquely the input, during form generation. Maybe you can go with other approach and use a css selector. Based on that you can alter the element on nested:fieldAdded event.

```
$('#trading_address').on 'nested:fieldAdded', (event) ->
  filed = event.field;
  filed.find('select').select2();
```

Within this example when the field is added, the `select` element is searched and `select2` is applied to it.

Similar you can add a `change` event in which some javascript is called. Something like:

```
filed.change(function(){  
 ... do stuff
});
```